# tensorflow training a CNN with 6 layers

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, training-data

I'm having problem training a CNN with 6 layers...
I'm processing black and white picture 64x64 bit in size...
I have 150k samples and approx 800 classes of images
I'm trying to implement a CNN with 6 layers..but i'm experiencing troubles during training...trainig accuracy is always low even ater 300 or 400 epochs of training...and the value is always similar...so I think there should be a big mistake somewhere but I haven't found it yet.
I've a class dataset (no implementation given here that has 3 members..
dataset.train, dataset.test, dataset.validation and every member has a method next_batch that sfuffle and returns the sample correctly (that was the first thing I tought I missed). I tried also to use hot one encoding of tensorflow, but don't know if the usage is correct..or there is a smarter one. Beside that as the test set does not fit in my graphic card memory I do the test validation in batches and then calculate the accuracy.
I've also tried to reduce the data set and the number of classes but same results...so I thought that was a problem related to my model...
(network architectures is derived from [This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf))
I tried to change the number of neurons for the fully connected layer and also the batch size but no luck...
anyone can point me in the right direction?

That's the output I got...

```
# Image size is also equal to the number of feature...imagine a flat image :)
img_width = 64
img_height = 64
image_size = img_width * img_height
num_classes = 800


# training data and labels
# First dimension (set to None. will be the batch number aka the number of sample used
# at the same time in our training...Setting to None let us choose dynamically
# whatever value)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, image_size])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes])
# Dropout keep probability
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Those will helper function to initialize be our weight and our biases of the network...
def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

# Convolutional of size x and strides 1 so initial image size is kept
# padding=SAME
def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

# 2 x 2 max pool with stride 2
def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')



######################################
# First layer Convolution 
######################################
# 3x3 patch, 1 input channel (the image), 32 output channels
W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

# Reshape our image to matrix multiply and number of colors channel (we have B/N images)
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, img_width, img_height , 1])
# multiply and then Relu
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
# and then dropout
h_drop1 = tf.nn.dropout(h_conv1, keep_prob)


######################################
# Second layer Convolution M6-1 network
######################################
# 3x3 patch, 32 input channel (the previous output channels), 32 output channels
W_conv2 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 32])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])

# multiply and then Relu
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_drop1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
# and the max pool (so image is now 32 x 32)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
# and then dropout
h_drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(h_pool2, keep_prob)
######################################
# Third layer Convolution M6-1 network
######################################
# 3x3 patch, 32 input channel (the previous output channels), 64 output channels
W_conv3 = weight_variable([3, 3, 32, 64])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([64])

# multiply and then Relu
h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_drop2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
# and then dropout
h_drop3 = tf.nn.dropout(h_conv3, keep_prob)

######################################
# Forth layer Convolution M6-1 network
######################################
# 3x3 patch, 64 input channel (the previous output channels), 64 output channels
W_conv4 = weight_variable([3, 3, 64, 64])
b_conv4 = bias_variable([64])

# multiply and then Relu
h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_drop3, W_conv4) + b_conv4)
# and the max pool image is now 16 x 16
h_pool4 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv4)
# and then dropout
h_drop4 = tf.nn.dropout(h_pool4, keep_prob)


######################################
# Fifth layer fully connected M6-1 network
######################################
# Fully connected layer
# Our image is now 16 x 16 after 2 max pools...and we have 64 channels so
# we want a matrix 16 * 16 * 64 and then 256 neurons
W_fc1 = weight_variable([16 * 16 * 64, 256])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([256])

h_pool4_flat = tf.reshape(h_drop4, [-1, 16 * 16 * 64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool4_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

######################################
# Output layer fully connected M6-1 network
######################################
# Fully connected layer
# Our image is now 16 x 16 after 2 max pools...and we have 256 channels so
# we want a matrix 16 * 16 * 64 and then 256 neurons
W_fc2 = weight_variable([256, num_classes])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([num_classes])

# Softmax classifier
y_predict = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_predict), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_predict,1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

batch_size = 128
max_train_epoch = 1000
while dataset.train.epochs_completed != max_train_epoch:
    batch = dataset.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    y_hot_one = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(labels=batch[1], num_classes=num_classes)
    if dataset.train.index_in_epoch %  10 * batch_size == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(session=sess, \
            feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: y_hot_one.eval(session=sess), keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("epoch: %d step %d, training accuracy %g" \
            % (dataset.train.epochs_completed, dataset.train.index_in_epoch, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(session=sess, \
        feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: y_hot_one.eval(session=sess), keep_prob: 0.5})

start = 0
size = 1000
if dataset.test.num_examples < size:
    end = dataset.test.num_examples
else:
    end = size

count = 1
total = []
print "Total test Example ", dataset.test.num_examples
while end <= dataset.test.num_examples:
    print "Start index ", start, " end ", end
    test_label_hot_one = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(labels=dataset.test.labels[start:end], num_classes=num_classes)
    correct = correct_prediction.eval(session=sess, \
        feed_dict={x: dataset.test.data[start:end], y_: test_label_hot_one.eval(session=sess), keep_prob: 1.0})
    start = end
    end += size
    if end > dataset.test.num_examples:
        end = dataset.test.num_examples
    total.extend(np.ravel(correct))

#print "total = ", total
total_corrected = sum(total)
#print type(summa)
percentage = (total_corrected / float(dataset.test.num_examples)) * 100
print("Test accuracy %g %d/%d" %  (percentage, total_corrected, dataset.test.num_examples))
```

And when I run the code...

```
> BlockquoteI tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:839] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
epoch: 0 step 640, training accuracy 0.015625
epoch: 0 step 1280, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 1920, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 2560, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 3200, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 3840, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 4480, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 5120, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 5760, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 6400, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 7040, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 7680, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 8320, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 8960, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 9600, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 10240, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 10880, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 11520, training accuracy 0.0078125
epoch: 0 step 12160, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 12800, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 13440, training accuracy 0
epoch: 0 step 14080, training accuracy 0.0078125
```

If I reduce the size of dataset (12k samples) and also the number of labels 75
I got...

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:839] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
epoch: 0 step 640, training accuracy 0.0078125
epoch: 0 step 1280, training accuracy 0.015625
epoch: 0 step 1920, training accuracy 0.015625
epoch: 0 step 2560, training accuracy 0.0234375
epoch: 0 step 3200, training accuracy 0.0234375
epoch: 0 step 3840, training accuracy 0.03125
epoch: 0 step 4480, training accuracy 0.0234375
epoch: 0 step 5120, training accuracy 0.0078125
epoch: 0 step 5760, training accuracy 0.0078125
epoch: 0 step 6400, training accuracy 0.0078125
epoch: 0 step 7040, training accuracy 0.0234375
Epochs completed  1
epoch: 1 step 640, training accuracy 0
epoch: 1 step 1280, training accuracy 0.015625
epoch: 1 step 1920, training accuracy 0.0234375
epoch: 1 step 2560, training accuracy 0
epoch: 1 step 3200, training accuracy 0.015625
epoch: 1 step 3840, training accuracy 0.015625
epoch: 1 step 4480, training accuracy 0.015625
epoch: 1 step 5120, training accuracy 0.03125
epoch: 1 step 5760, training accuracy 0.0234375
epoch: 1 step 6400, training accuracy 0.0234375
epoch: 1 step 7040, training accuracy 0.0234375
```

And the number remains almost like those even after 500 epochs of training.

Any one can point me in the right direction?
Regards.

Comment: You could try with an even smaller dataset (like 100 images) and try to overfit it.

Comment: I tryed it but with no success...the network is not overfitting....so I'm even more convinced that I have a big bug in my code...even if I can't find it :)

Comment: Try with 100 images and much less convolutions, like only 2 convolutions / max pooling, it will be easier to optimize